# Change AutoGeneratedDelete LinkButton of Gridview to an Image Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

i have a gridview with AutoGenerateDeleteButton Property set true.
Of course this property auto generates a linkbutton at the leftmost of the gridview, my question is, how can i change it to an Image Button?? i wanted my gridview to look more presentable by making the control buttons an image.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using template in grid...

for more info

http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-2-0-professional/46216-image-button-template-field-gridview-control.html

Comment: i wanted to do it in code behind since my gridview is dynamic. 
how can i do that?? Thanks @vino20

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Columns>
   <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/DeleteImage.png"
      ShowDeleteButton="true"/>
</Columns>
```

And set `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"`

Or Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277393/how-do-i-use-images-instead-of-text-for-autogenerateeditbutton-in-asp-net-gridvi) too

Comment: why does it have a lot of image URLs??

Comment: i tried this but the content of my gridview went missing.
im using AutoGeneratedColumns = true and i set my gridview's datasource to a datatable.

Comment: i tried that rowdatabound but linkbutton has no image property

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TemplateField` and use  `autogeneratecolumns="false"`.

Here's an example of a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Link" runat="server" Text="click" OnClick="link_Click"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field1" HeaderText="My Column 1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field2" HeaderText="My Column 2" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where `field1` and `field2` are headers from your `DataTable`

And to access the row within the event handler:

```
protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
    //do something with rowindex etc
}
```

Comment: i cant set AutogenerateColumns = false because i am setting my datasource to a datatable.

Comment: You don't necessarily need autogeneratecolumns for using datatable. I'll edit my answer to give an example of this.

Comment: the problem is, my datatable is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Add new Template Column and in  add image button and set CommandName='Delete' it'll raise the delete event automatically.

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" ImageUrl="~/imgs/Delete.png" 
              CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```